# Java Spring validation doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, error-handling

I have following problem: I made some error handling in controller, mostly to prevent duplicate entries in DB. I did the exacact thing in another controller and this second one doesn't work.

The first one, that works (only fragments of the code):

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="batch")
public class Batch {

    @Min(value=1, message="Invalid number")
    @Column(name="batch_number")
    private Integer batchNumber;
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/batch")
public class BatchController {

@Autowired
private BatchService batchService;

@PostMapping("/saveBatch")
public String saveBatch(@Valid @ModelAttribute("batch") Batch theBatch, BindingResult theBindingResult) {

if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    return "batch-form";
}
else {
    try {
        batchService.saveBatch(theBatch);

        return "redirect:/batch/list";

    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        theBindingResult.rejectValue("batchNumber", "batchNumber.error", "Invalid number");
        return "batch-form";
    }
}
```

}

JSP:

```
<tr>
    <td><label>Batch number:</label></td>
    <td><form:input path="batchNumber"/></td>
    <td><form:errors path="batchNumber" cssClass="error" /></td>
</tr>
```

The same goes for mvc that doesn't work:

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="country")
public class Country {

    @NotNull(message="This field is required")
    @Size(min=1, message="This field is required")
    @Column(name="country_name")
    private String countryName;
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/country")
public class CountryController {

    // need to inject country service
    @Autowired
    CountryService countryService;

@PostMapping("/saveCountry")
    public String saveCountry(@Valid @ModelAttribute("country") Country theCountry, BindingResult theBindingResult) {

        if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "country-form";
        }
        else {
            try {
                countryService.saveCountry(theCountry);

                return "redirect:/country/list";

            } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
                theBindingResult.rejectValue("countryName", "countryName.error", "Invalid country name");
                return "country-form";
            }
        }
    }
```

JSP:

```
<tr>
    <td><label>Country name:</label></td>
    <td><form:input path="countryName"/></td>
    <td><form:errors path="countryName" cssClass="error" /></td>
</tr>
```

When I'm trying to save duplicate value for `Batch` entity, I receive the proper message. I can't get this message when I'm trying to add duplicate `Country`. Instead, I get `HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error`.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Could you please provide the full error log trace?

Comment: Sure: https://pastebin.com/b2u8KzXW

Comment: Well, the error trace clearly says `Duplicate entry 'asd' for key 'country_name'`. Could you check if you are passing the same values again and again?

Comment: Yes - I'm passing the same string. When I'm trying to add Batch with the same number, I get notification on jsp page, and there is something like this in logs: `ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]`. I want the same for `Country`

Comment: It's not a validation error then, it's a database error. Your validation probably works just fine. Also, maybe use NotEmpty instead of NotNull and Size. To handle database errors, you will need a ControllerAdvice.